# compile error: #error "This file should be compiled in ARM mode only."

Tags: ios, ipad, compilation, compiler-errors, arm

I have the compile error when trying to install app into my ipad 4:

## error "This file should be compiled in ARM mode only."

What happen and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

the app probably compiled for the IOS simulator and not for an actual device,
it is exactly what it says, should be compiled for arm but you compiled for intel

Comment: how are you exporting the ipa? are you just hitting "play"? or exporting ipa and then moving it to the device?

Comment: I build and run the app, if that answer your question.